# Activating vitualenv within Supervisord

Tags: celery, django-celery, supervisord

For a little bit of background.  I am using Supervisor to monitor a django-celery process.  I need to be able to set the virutalenv then start the celeryd process.

The way that I am currently doing it is by, in the `supervisor.conf` file I have

```
[program:celery]  
command = /srv/worker.sh

stdout_logfile = /srv/supervisor.log
stderr_logfile = /srv/supervisor.log
```

Then in `worker.sh` I have

```
/bin/su - username -c "source /srv/virtualenvs/bin/activate; python /srv/manage.py celeryd
```

This works, sort of.  The problem is that when I `supervisorctl stop celery` with supervisor it does not kill the workers.  They still remain.  I'm thinking if I am able to activate the virtualenv within supervisor, everything will work better than dropping into a shell script.

Comment: It's not necessary to `source bin/activate` a virtualenv to run something. Simply run using the virtualenv's python. Eg: `/srv/virtualenvs/bin/python /srv/manage.py`

Comment: Check out https://github.com/mher/celery-deploy. It manages celeryd processes with supervisord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TERM signal is getting sent to the shell script instead of celeryd. Either don't use it (because you can set the user from the supervisord conf) or use exec.

Anyway, best practice is (if you don't care about losing some tasks): short stopwaitsecs and killasgroup=true.

Eg:

```
[program:celery]
command=celeeryd blablabla
user=username 
stopwaitsecs=10
killasgroup=true
```